# Meaning of "Scarce"

Tags: meaning, books

I'm reading Time Machine by H. G. Wells.

And there is a sentence:

"At first I scarce thought of stopping, scarce thought of anything but these new sensations".

What does "scarce" mean in this context? Usually "scarce" means "not very much of something", but in this case .. it is like "to be scared of". Is that mistake or.. maybe it is "scarce usage of this word"?

Comment: _Scarce_ is just short for _scarcely_, which is a negative trigger like _hardly_ and means the same thing. _He had hardly/scarcely chopped anything when the knife bent._ Without the _-ly_, it's archaic, hence falutes higher.

Comment: And without the -ly of its larger brother, is known as a _flat adverb_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a mistake as I've encountered this phrase "scarce thought of" elsewhere.
Scarce = not much 
So I think it means:
I didn't think much about(consider) stopping, I didn't think much(consider) about anything but these new sensations.

Answer (score 1):

*Scarce* is an adverb here meaning "hardly" or "almost not at all." Oxford Dictionaries label it archaic; Merriam-Webster doesn't.